# How to get a property without initialize class?

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with my PHP code while trying to get an array.

**This is my code**

```
<?php
class Core{

    public $actions;

    public function __construct(){
        //set must be defined here
        $this->setter('this is the action');
    }

    public function returnAction(){
        // This method is just for testing purposes
        return $this->actions;
    }

    public function setter($actions){
        $this->actions = $actions;
    }

    public function getter(){
        return $this->actions;
    }

}

// If I try this, it throws an error, and of course it doesn't return the same as below:  Access to undeclared static property: Core::$actions 
echo Core::$actions;

// Same if I try this, I get this error: Using $this when not in object context
echo Core::returnAction();


// But if I do this, it works...
$class = new Core();

echo $class->actions;
```

In fact, it doesn't work for obvious reasons: class is not initialized in both cases. My question is... what are the best approaches to achieve this code running, without having to initialize the class?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you expect an OOP answer? Because simply wrapping code in a `class` doesn't make your code OOP.

Comment: Well, I'm actually moving all my legacy PHP code to OOP, using an adaptation of my old framework, so, may this could'nt be considered as OOP, but the intention is to make it running into a OOP en environment.

Comment: Ok Fair enough. Whenever you do `Whatever::doShit()` or `Whatever::shit` (unless you are doing `self::doShit()` or `parent::doShit()`) it has nothing to do with OOP. That is a static call and is the exact opposite of OOP.

Comment: That's an awesome tip I've learnt today! Thank you very much, that was a very good lesson! I'll try to make it work in another way.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a non-static method:

```
public function returnAction(){
    // This method is just for testing purposes
    return $this->actions;
}
```

But you're doing a static call:

```
echo Core::returnAction();
```

When you are doing a static call, the function will be called (even if not static). 
But as there is no instance of an object, there is no $this.

Correct way of calling this method is like so:

```
$foo = new Core();
echo $foo->returnActions();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to access a public property or method without instantiating a class by using the [static keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

So you would do: `public static $actions;`.

This said, your class really looks like it was designed to be instantiated as there is a constructor, setters, getters.

I would simply rewrite it like this:

```
class Core{
    public static $actions;
}
```

Enjoy!

UPDATED AFTER COMMENT FROM @Melvin

Comment: No you can't do that. You're not allowed to use $this when not in object context.